# Name for functions that deal with Redux state (e.g. reducers and selectors)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need help naming functions that act on a slice of Redux state. What would be a good name for the type of functions that reducers and selectors are? I came up with `stateHandler`, but it's too wordy and generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on coming up with a term that handles both the "reducer" level and the "selector" level of this pattern, (and you don't like reducer, since it pretty much is reducers all the way down), you could consider the term "transformer" since you are taking an input and old state, and creating a transformed result.

Comment: Thanks I like that a lot. Could you clarify what you mean by saying "it's reducers all the way down"? Are you saying that selectors could be classified as reducers?

Comment: The only real differences are that the top level functions called reducers can be composed directly in the redux api, and they consume action objects that must have a type property, whereas you are responsible for dispatching the actions inside the reducer (presumably by examining type), and you glue all the relevant functions together yourself).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned these are also called reducers. Cf the documentation:

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an
>   action, and returns the next state. (previousState, action) =>
>   newState. It's called a reducer because it's the type of function you
>   would pass to Array.prototype.reduce(reducer, ?initialValue).

I sometimes add a prefix to specify what that reducer is: `userReducer`, `productReducer` and so on ...

Then within a reducer itself I will usually call the action handler function the same as the action name. For example:

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return addTodo(state, action); // then put your addTodo function above or in a different file
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return toggleTodo(state, action); // idem
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, reducers and selectors are both functions that deal with Redux state. I'm trying to come up with a term to describe both of them in the same breath.